# Show that the function $15x^5-10x^3+3x-1$ is bijective and at which point is the inverse differentiable?

Tags: calculus

> $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\;\; x \mapsto 15x^5-10x^3+3x-1$

I had the idea that the function is odd and strictly increasing so it has to be bijective. If I take the first derivative I get $$f'(x)=75x^4-30x^2+3$$ so I have to prove that $f'(x)=75x^4-30x^2+3 > 0.$

I got that $75x^4>30x^2.$
Is my assumption correct? And how can I find at which point is the inverse differentiable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Careful saying $75x^4 > 30x^2$. Plug in $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and you will see this is false. You need to list the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The derivative factors as $3(5x^2-1)^2$.